# Not able to Receive Message From SNS

Tags: amazon-sns

In the below Code

```
        PublishRequest publishRequest = new PublishRequest()
        {
            Message = $"Hello from SNS",
            PhoneNumber = "+91-XXXXXXXXXX"
        };
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(simpleNotificationServiceClient.Config));
        var response = await simpleNotificationServiceClient.PublishAsync(publishRequest);
```

I Got StatusCode from the response as 200 but did not get the message.

P.S: My SNSClient has Admin Access but still I am facing this issue. Region :us-east-1

Comment: FYI, India has some restrictions on using Sender IDs ([Supported Regions and countries - Amazon Simple Notification Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-supported-regions-countries.html#sms-support-note-1)) and India requires pre-registered Sender IDs. However, I notice you aren't using one, so that probably isn't causing the issue.

Comment: I am not using any SenderIds in my request. However, I have my company account from which Messages were getting published to my mobile whereas mine is a freetier account. I don't know why I am not getting SMS.

Comment: I did some experimentation (in Australia) and found that my carrier was blocking messages as Spam if they had a Sender ID. My Sender ID was set in my Preferences, rather than being defined on the message itself. You can activate Delivery status logging in CloudWatch Logs by following these instructions: [Monitor Amazon SNS Text Message Delivery Using CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch/)